# How do I optimize a function subject to a two-part constraint?

Tags: optimization, economics, discrete-optimization, utility

I would like to maximize the following function

$$\max\; U= log(xT_o + (1-x)T_s) + log(Y)$$

by choosing levels of $T_o$, $T_s$, and $Y$, and where $x\in[0:1]$

subject to

$$N = \binom{P_sT_s+Y \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \text{if} \; T_o=0}{P_sT_s+P_oT_o+P_f+P_a+Y \quad \text{if} \; T_o>0}$$

How do I go about solving this? Looking into economics literature on contingent commodities, I suspect there might be a way to collapse the constraint down into a single equation, but I'm not sure how.

If it helps to have some context, I'm making a simple economic model, and the idea is that there is a utility function that depends on consumption of three goods, $T_o$, $T_s$, and $Y$. There are fixed costs $P_f$ and $P_a$ associated with choosing to consume at least one unit of $T_o$. $P_o$ and $P_s$ are the marginal costs of $T_o$ and $T_s$, respectively. $N$ is the individual's endowment.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers, no?

Comment: I'm familiar in general with optimizing functions subject to a constraint using Lagrangian. My confusion arises from the fact the constraint is not continuous.

Comment: I have some ideas here, but the problem is that if $T_o=0$, the first term is $-\infty$. So your utility function seems to force $T_o$ to be positive, making the constraint irrelevant. What am I missing? (I'm comfortable with constrained optimization, just not economics, so I might be missing a convention.)

Comment: Sorry @MichaelC.Grant, you're right. I changed the utility function at the last second thinking it would make it simpler, but it actually just messed it up as you pointed out. I've edited the question to fix it. The only idea is that $T_s$ and $T_o$ are substitute goods, and $Y$ is all other goods (money)

Comment: Is $x$ is fixed?

Comment: Yes, $x$ just represents the consumer's preference over the two options $T_o$ and $T_s$. Optimal consumption of each good should end up as a function of $x$ and all the the prices. Also, my notation on the max function in the original question may have been wrong, so I edited it to make to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the OP for the clarifications. I have a couple of suggestions.

First of all, we know that $T_o \leq T_{\max} \triangleq ( N - P_f - P_a - Y ) / P_s$ (which I assume is positive, otherwise the model is infeasible.) We'll use this later.

One strategy is this to solve two models: the "positive model" that uses the $T_o>0$ constraint, producing a utility value $U_+$; and the "zero model" that uses the $T_o=0$ constraint, producing a utility value $U_0$. Then pick the model that produces the larger utility.

If by chance solving the positive model happens to return $T_o=0$, you can be *sure* that the zero model will yield a higher utility value. Here's why: let $(0,\bar{T}_s,\bar{Y})$ be the specific values that come out of the positive model. Then the point $(0,\bar{T}_s,\bar{Y}+P_f+P_a)$ will be a *feasible* solution to the zero model. It will not necessarily be optimal, but it will already have a higher utility value:
$$U_{+}\geq\log((1-x)\bar{T}_s)+\log(\bar{Y}+P_f+P_a) \geq \log((1-x)\bar{T}_s)+\log(\bar{Y}) = U_{0}.$$
So if both models suggest $T_o=0$, you can be sure that the zero model will win every time. (If your utility function weren't concave this might not be so.)

Now, if you want to be able to handle more general models, and you happen to have a convex optimization engine around that can handle binary variables, have it solve this model:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize}   & \log(xT_o+(1-x)T_s)+\log Y \\
\text{subject to} & N = P_sT_s + P_oT_o + B(P_f+P_a) + Y \\
                  & T_s, T_o \geq 0 \\
                  & T_o \leq B T_{\max} \\
                  & B\in\{0,1\}
\end{array}$$
To see why this works, note that if $B=0$, then the $T_o\leq BT_{\max}$ constraint forces $T_o=0$, and it also removes the fixed costs from the budget constraint. If $B=1$, then $T_o\leq T_{\max}$ lets $T_o$ take on any sensible value, but it adds the fixed cost back in.

Now, what a solver is likely to do here is to first solve the problem by replacing $B\in\{0,1\}$ with $0\leq B \leq 1$. If the optimal solution to this relaxed problem has either $B=0$ or $B=1$, then it will *stop*, knowing that it has the right answer to the original as well. Otherwise, it will effectively try both $B=0$ and $B=1$ separately. (For problems with more binary variables, solvers typically do more advanced things with cutting planes etc., but for one variable, I'm almost certain this is how it will go.)

EDITED to add: if you use my software [CVX](http://cvxr.com) to solve this problem, here is the model I would use:

```
cvx_begin
   cvx_solver mosek % or gurobi
   variables To Ts Y
   variable B binary
   maximize(geo_mean([x*To+(1-x)*Ts Y]))
   subject to
      N == Ps * Ts + Po * To + B * ( Pf + Pa ) + Y
      0 <= To <= B * ( N − Pf − Pa − Y ) / Ps
      Ts >= 0
cvx_end
```

This objective, $\sqrt{(xT_o+(1-x)T_s)Y}$, is compatible with the solvers under the hood; and it's related to your original objective by a logarithm and scaling, so it's equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer! If I can clarify a couple of points:

Comment: (continuation from prev comment)  (1) The addition of the $B$ is interesting. I had thought about a similar approach, reducing the constraint to $$N=P_sT_s+T_o(P_o+(P_f+P_a)/T_o)+Y$$, but it just ended up cancelling out and the answer was unchanged (plus the problem of dividing by 0 when $T_o=0$). Can you explain how this approach is different? (2) "..and you happen to have a convex optimization engine around.." Would MATLAB with the symbolic math toolbox be able to handle something like this? Or are you thinking something more like GAMS?

Comment: 1) Well, my approach is convex (when the integer constraint is relaxed). That's a big deal from a tractability standpoint.

Comment: 2) You could use my software [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx) on MATLAB, with two caveats. First of all, the only solvers that can handle the nonlinearity and the integer constraints are MOSEK and Gurobi, which are commercial, but if you're an academic you can get a license pretty quickly (quickest for MOSEK, not so bad for Gurobi either). The second caveat: Instead of using the logarithm, use this objective instead: `geo_mean([x*To+(1-x)*Ts Y])`. These solvers don't handle the logarithm, but they can handle this, and it will give the same result.

Comment: I edited my answer to show you what it looks like in CVX.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. Am I right in understanding that if I were to solve this using a solver as you suggest, I would need to do so numerically? (Sorry if that's a dumb question). Ultimately, I'm trying to keep the results of the model completely symbolic, so I can just show that consumption of the three goods is a function of _____ (whatever it ends up being). But to use a solver, I'd have to actually supply values for x, z, and the prices, right?

Comment: Hmm. If the model remains this simple you might be able to go about this symbolically, or nearly so. Do what I was talking about at first: solve both models and pick the one with the best utility. But I have not tried.

Comment: Thank you. I will use the simple approach of solving them individually. Unfortunately, I'm having problems solving the "positive model," but I'll make that the subject of another question (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674521/what-is-the-solution-to-this-system-of-3-equations) and consider this one answered. Thank you!